# How can git be installed on CENTOS 5.5?

Tags: git, centos5

How can I install git on CENTOS 5.5 machine?
I tried to install it from yum but got following msg.

```
root@host [~]# sudo yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * extras: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * updates: pubmirrors.reflected.net
addons                                                   |  951 B     00:00
base                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package git available.
Nothing to do
root@host [~]#
```

Comment: On later versions of CentOS, using the standard 'yum install git' seems to work just fine.

Comment: yum install git-core also works.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From source? From the repos? The easiest way is to use the repos: `sudo yum install git` should do it. It may first be necessary to set up an additional repo such as [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) first if git is not provided by the main repos.

If you want to install from source, you can try [these](http://www.how-to-linux.com/2009/01/install-git-161-on-centos-52/) instructions. If you have `yum-utils` installed it's actually easier than that, too**:

```
sudo yum build-dep git
wget http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/<latest-git-source>.tar.gz
tar -xvjf <latest-git>.tar.gz
cd <git>
make (possibly a ./configure before this)
sudo make install
```

**Substitute the portions enclosed in `<>` with the paths you need. Exact procedure may vary slightly as I have not compiled git from source, personally (there may be a configure script, for example). If you have no idea what I'm talking about, then you may want to just install from the repo as per my first suggestion.

Comment: I tried to install it from yum but it says "No package git available"

Comment: @Prakash: It looks like git is not in the standard CentOS repositories. You can either install from source or set up the EPEL repo on your machine: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL. Also, you may want to consider asking this question on Superuser/Serverfault if you need more help.

Comment: @Rimian: I know that link manages to install git and gitweb too, but its focus is on gitosis, which is unmaintained and completely superseded by gitolite.

Comment: It will even give an error when you try to git init. Now how will I uninstall this one?!

Comment: @ElsonSolano: `yum remove git`. See CentOS's [yum documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/) for additional information.

Comment: `sudo yum install epel-release` and `sudo yum install git` work great on Red Hat as well.  (RHEL).

Comment: @Jess Very useful, simple answer. Thanks. Suggest you post this as an answer, because it was direct and not complicated.

Comment: ***`make (possibly a ./configure before this)`*** - Are you kidding me??? Do you know how many things can go wrong due to PCRE, cURL, OpenSSL and other dependent library problems. Git silently swallows its configuration errors. Your first clone will fail for no apparent reason. After suffering a number of "build Git from sources", I'm now looking for a package-managed version.

Answer (score 135):

If you are using CentOS the built in `yum` repositories don't seem to have `git` included and as such, you will need to add an additional repository to the system. For my servers I found that the [Webtatic](http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) repository seems to be reasonably up to date and the installation for `git` will then be as follows:

```
# Add the repository
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm

# Install the latest version of git
yum install --enablerepo=webtatic git-all
```

To work around `Missing Dependency: perl(Git)` errors:

```
yum install --enablerepo=webtatic --disableexcludes=main  git-all
```

Comment: @coure2011 - Seems like I can get to it through my browser, what sort of error exactly are you getting?

Comment: This is really good but the dl.fedoraproject.org version may be a better option for some (for me, I had an odd conflict with a perl SVN integration tool with this package so had to use the Fedora version instead).

Comment: This also includes GUI tools and a lot of dependencies. You can use `yum install git` to get only the base install.

Comment: Here's the link to webtatic's instructions: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/git17/

Comment: I didn't want to make the commitment of adding a new repo, so I just web-browsed to [http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/](http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/) and cherry-picked the RPM files I needed.

Comment: I get this error summary when following that instruciton: http://elsonsolano.com/screenshot/2012-07-18_1555.png

Comment: @ElsonSolano: Note the the x86_64 and i386 descriptors on the packages. You're trying to install mismatching architectures (looks like 64-bit on a 32-bit environment). I would check your Webtatic configuration if that's the repo you're using.

Comment: just a comment to say thanks for a great answer - this really helped

Comment: I only needed the last line. Where `yum install git` didn't work, `yum install --disableexcludes=main  git-all` did. Thanks.

Comment: Same here, I only needed `yum install --disableexcludes=main git-all`

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: Confirmed, the second line does the job.

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 34):

Just:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install git-core
```

Comment: Note that that "download.fedora.redhat.com" is now "dl.fedoraproject.org" but this still works.

Comment: This answer is much better than building from source.   It's much easier to manage packages on a continuing basis with yum.

Comment: Worked fine (Centos 5.9)

Comment: In addition to the 2 commands above, I had to execute "sudo yum install git" to get git binary. I am on centOS 5.9

Answer (score 25):

I've tried few methods from this question and they all failed on my CentOs, either because of the wrong repos or missing files.

Here is the method which works for me (when installing version 1.7.8):

```
    yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel cpio expat-devel gettext-devel
    wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.8.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf ./git-1.7.8.tar.gz
    cd ./git-1.7.8
    ./configure
    make
    make install
```

You may want to download a different version from here:
http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list

Comment: isn't there a reliable way of configuring something from source as a package?

Comment: Do you mean to create a new package? I guess you can always do so, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880227/what-is-the-minimum-i-have-to-do-to-create-an-rpm-file

Comment: I had the same trouble and had to use this approach too. For searchability, here are some of the errors I ran into when trying to install via webtatic or EPEL package approach: "Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)", "Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.7.3-1.w5 is needed by package git-1.7.7.3-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)". No errors when installing using the method specified in this answer.

Comment: I did this using downloading version 1.7.12 and it could not git clone a https url saying that https is not supported. it tried another answer from user SCL using dl.fedoraproject.org as per the comment on that answer and it worked well.

Answer (score 14):

For installing git

1. install last epel-release

> rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

1. Install git from repository

> yum install git

Comment: Git 1.8 is kind of old. The script below provides 2.12, which is the latest as of this writing.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sure this question is about to die now that RHEL 5 is nearing end of life, but the answer seems to have gotten a lot simpler now:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install git
```

worked for me on a fresh install of CentOS 5.11.

Answer (score 6):

```
yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel cpio expat-devel gettext-devel gcc
wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.11.4.tar.gz
tar zxvf git-1.7.11.4.tar.gz 
cd git-1.7.11.4
./configure 
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, there is more to it than that, you need zlib.  zlib is part of CentOS, but you need the development form to get zlib.h ... notice that the yum name of zlib development
is quite different possibly than for apt-get on ubuntu/debian, what follows actually works
with my CentOS version 

in particular, you do ./configure on git, then try make, and the first build fails with missing zlib.h

I used a two-step procedure to resolve this
a) Got RPMFORGE for my version of CentOS

See: 
www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=18506&forum=38
and this:
wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

In my case [as root, or with sudo]

```
$ wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
$ rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm
$ rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm
## Note: the RPM for rpmforge is small (like 12.3K) but don't let that fool
## you; it augments yum the next time you use yum
## [this is the name that YUM found] (still root or sudo)
$ yum install zlib-devel.x86_64
## and finally in the source directory for git (still root or sudo):
$ ./configure (this worked before, but I ran it again to be sure)
$ make
$ make install
```

(this install put it by default in `/usr/local/bin/git` ... not my favorite choice, but OK for the default)... and git works fine!

Comment: You can format your answer using Markdown rather than using HTML directly. It's easier to edit for others.

Comment: git is in rpmforge, so all you have to do is add rpmforge to your list of repositories and install: http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B => add rpmforge => yum install git-all (that's it)

Comment: ^ This seems like by far the best soluion

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the repos for CentOS 5 are disappearing. Most of the ones mentioned in this question are no longer online, don't seem to have Git, or have a really old version of Git. Below is the script I use to build OpenSSL, IDN2, PCRE, cURL and Git from sources. Both the `git://` and `https://` protocols will be available for cloning.

Over time the names of the archives will need to be updates. For example, as of this writing, `openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz` is the latest available in the 1.0.2 family.

Dale Anderson's answer using RHEL repos looks good at the moment, but its a fairly old version. Red Hat provides Git version 1.8, while the script below builds 2.12 from sources.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# OpenSSL installs into lib64/, while cURL installs into lib/
INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local
INSTALL_LIB32="$INSTALL_ROOT/lib"
INSTALL_LIB64="$INSTALL_ROOT/lib64"

OPENSSL_TAR=openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz
OPENSSL_DIR=openssl-1.0.2k

ZLIB_TAR=zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
ZLIB_DIR=zlib-1.2.11

UNISTR_TAR=libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz
UNISTR_DIR=libunistring-0.9.7

IDN2_TAR=libidn2-0.16.tar.gz
IDN2_DIR=libidn2-0.16

PCRE_TAR=pcre2-10.23.tar.gz
PCRE_DIR=pcre2-10.23

CURL_TAR=curl-7.53.1.tar.gz
CURL_DIR=curl-7.53.1

GIT_TAR=v2.12.2.tar.gz
GIT_DIR=git-2.12.2

###############################################################################

# I don't like doing this, but...
read -s -p "Please enter password for sudo: " SUDO_PASSWWORD

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** zLib **********"

wget "http://www.zlib.net/$ZLIB_TAR" -O "$ZLIB_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download zLib"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$ZLIB_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$ZLIB_TAR"
cd "$ZLIB_DIR"

LIBS="-ldl -lpthread" ./configure --enable-shared --libdir="$INSTALL_LIB64"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure zLib"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build zLib"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S make install

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Unistring **********"

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/$UNISTR_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$UNISTR_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$UNISTR_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$UNISTR_TAR"
cd "$UNISTR_DIR"

LIBS="-ldl -lpthread" ./configure --enable-shared --libdir="$INSTALL_LIB64"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S make install

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** IDN **********"

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/$IDN2_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$IDN2_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$IDN2_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$IDN2_TAR"
cd "$IDN2_DIR"

LIBS="-ldl -lpthread" ./configure --enable-shared --libdir="$INSTALL_LIB64"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S make install

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** OpenSSL **********"

wget "https://www.openssl.org/source/$OPENSSL_TAR" -O "$OPENSSL_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download OpenSSL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$OPENSSL_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$OPENSSL_TAR"
cd "$OPENSSL_DIR"

# OpenSSL and enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_12 option
IS_X86_64=$(uname -m 2>&1 | egrep -i -c "(amd64|x86_64)")

CONFIG=./config
CONFIG_FLAGS=(no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp shared "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIB64" --prefix="$INSTALL_ROOT" --openssldir="$INSTALL_ROOT")
if [[ "$IS_X86_64" -eq "1" ]]; then
    CONFIG_FLAGS+=("enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128")
fi

"$CONFIG" "${CONFIG_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure OpenSSL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make depend
make -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build OpenSSL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S make install_sw

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** PCRE **********"

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre//$PCRE_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$PCRE_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download PCRE"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$PCRE_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$PCRE_TAR"
cd "$PCRE_DIR"

make configure
CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_ROOT/include" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIB64 -L$INSTALL_LIB64" \
    LIBS="-lidn2 -lz -ldl -lpthread" ./configure --enable-shared --enable-pcre2-8 --enable-pcre2-16 --enable-pcre2-32 \
    --enable-unicode-properties --enable-pcregrep-libz --prefix="$INSTALL_ROOT" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIB64"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure PCRE"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make all -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build PCRE"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S make install

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** cURL **********"

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://curl.haxx.se/download/$CURL_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$CURL_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download cURL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$CURL_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$CURL_TAR"
cd "$CURL_DIR"

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_ROOT/include" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIB64 -L$INSTALL_LIB64" \
    LIBS="-lidn2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --with-ssl="$INSTALL_ROOT" --with-libidn2="$INSTALL_ROOT" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIB64"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure cURL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build cURL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S make install

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Git **********"

wget "https://github.com/git/git/archive/$GIT_TAR" -O "$GIT_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$GIT_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$GIT_TAR"
cd "$GIT_DIR"

make configure
CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_ROOT/include" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIB64,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIB32 -L$INSTALL_LIB64 -L$INSTALL_LIB32" \
    LIBS="-lidn2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread" ./configure --with-openssl --with-curl --with-libpcre --prefix="$INSTALL_ROOT"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

make all -j 4

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to build Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE=make
MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! -z `which asciidoc 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no asciidoc'` ]]; then
    if [[ ! -z `which xmlto 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no xmlto'` ]]; then
        MAKE_FLAGS+=("install-doc" "install-html" "install-info")
    fi
fi

echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Cleanup **********"

rm -rf "$OPENSSL_TAR  $OPENSSL_DIR  $UNISTR_TAR  $UNISTR_DIR  $CURL_TAR  $CURL_DIR"
rm -rf "$PCRE_TAR $PCRE_DIR $ZLIB_TAR $ZLIB_DIR $IDN2_TAR $IDN2_DIR $GIT_TAR $GIT_DIR"

[[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 0 || return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just updating this for 2017 and later, as CentOS 5 has reached EOL and the URL for EPEL has changed:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install git
```

This gets you git 1.8.2.3

Comment: This the one that finally worked for me in December 2019

Answer (score 1):

Just installed git using the following instructions:

1. Install EPEL V5 
   `#rpm -Uvh http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`
2. Install Git
   `# yum install git git-daemon`
3. Check
   `# git --version`
   `git version 1.8.2.3`
4. Optionally install Git GUI 
    
   `# yum install git-gui`

For i386 substitute x86_64 by i386 in the URL at step #1.
`#rpm -Uvh http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on CentOS:

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel cpio expat-devel gettext-devel
   ```
2. Get Git

   ```
   cd /usr/local/src
   wget http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.8.3.tar.gz
   tar xvzf git-1.7.8.3.tar.gz
   cd git-1.7.8.3
   ```
3. Build Git

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

Comment: How is it different from existing answers?

Comment: I believe you need to configure Git with `--with-openssl` and `--with-curl` to get the HTTPS helpers. Otherwise, a `git clone https://github.com/...` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/Centos*` so that all lines that have `enabled = 0` instead have `enabled = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel cpio expat-devel gettext-devel

Get the required version of GIT from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/ 

wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/{version.gz}

tar -xzvf git-version.gz

cd git-version

./configure

make

make install
```