# How to serve GIT through HTTP via NGINX with user/password?

Tags: git, nginx

Despite all the links I've found on how to configure git/nginx to get my repos, I can't make them work.

I followed this tutorial, [Git repository over HTTP WebDAV with nginx](http://www.xiaoka.com/blog/2008/04/13/git-repository-over-http-webdav-with-nginx/), but the user/password restriction doesnt' work. Anyone can clone the repository.

I'm from a configuration using SVN + Apache + DAV_SVN, with a file for password (created with htpasswd), and a file for the authz. I'd like to do the same, using git+nginx. How's that possible ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at the following article, http://www.toofishes.net/blog/git-smart-http-transport-nginx/

It provides a sample nginx config:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  git.mydomain.com;

        location ~ /git(/.*) {
            # fcgiwrap is set up to listen on this host:port
            fastcgi_pass  localhost:9001;
            include       fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
            # export all repositories under GIT_PROJECT_ROOT
            fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
            fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /srv/git;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $1;
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is pass your repo which is located after /git in the url, to `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend`. Example, `http://git.mydomain.com/git/someapp` would point to the `someapp` repository. This repo would be located in `/srv/git/someapp` as defined in the `fastcgi_param` of `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` and can be changed to fit your server.

This is very useful and you can apply [`HttpAuthBasicModule`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule) to nginx to password protect your repo's access via HTTP.

**Edit:** If you are missing `git-http-backend`, you can install the `git-core` package on Ubuntu/Debian or on RPM based platforms look at [How can git be installed on CENTOS 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779274/how-can-git-be-installed-on-centos-5-5)

Comment: I followed this example to set up git on nginx. However each time I try clone repo I end up with error: 
`fatal: http://<ip>:9000/git/test.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git re
pository?`


There are no errors is /var/log/nginx/error.log and in access log I can see:

<my ip> - - [03/Oct/2015:08:35:42 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 424859 "-" "git/1.9.4.msysgit.1"

Did you run into similar problem maybe?
Thanks,
Janusz

Comment: no, but make sure its a bare repository created with `git init --bare`. ie, don't host checked out code, unless you are doing `git clone <repo> --bare` - other than that, the googles should help

Comment: I eventually found example that worked for me: http://serverfault.com/questions/483726/how-to-make-git-smart-http-transport-work-on-nginx. Thanks.

Comment: **ALSO**, run `git update-server-info` on the bare repository, I was getting 404's for an `.git/info/refs` file that this will generate.

Comment: In case you're curious, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313590/107158 illustrates how to configure `git-http-backend` to enable  *anonymous read access but authenticated write access*.

Comment: In my case, the fcgi didn't listen on any port but socket, all I had to do was to change
`fastcgi_pass  localhost:9001;` to `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/fcgiwrap.socket;`

Comment: Thanks @ThorSummoner, that was indeed the solution for my case. I'm unclear why this was necessary though, as similar setups seemed to always already have that file. I wonder if something changed in git causing this file not to exist by default any more

Answer (score 20):

Here is a full configuration for Git over HTTP, with TLS encryption, Basic Auth, and [GitWeb](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb). I assume that the repositories' root is in `/home/git`. You should replace `example.com` with your domain.

```
# Remove this block if you don't want TLS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl; # Replace 443 ssl by 80 if you don't want TLS
    server_name  git.example.com;
    root         /usr/share/gitweb; # Remove if you don't want Gitweb

    error_log  /home/git/nginx-error.log;
    access_log /home/git/nginx-access.log;

    # Remove ssl_* lines if you don't want TLS
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers               'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # Remove auth_* if you don't want HTTP Basic Auth
    auth_basic "example Git";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    # static repo files for cloning over https
    location ~ ^.*\.git/objects/([0-9a-f]+/[0-9a-f]+|pack/pack-[0-9a-f]+.(pack|idx))$ {
        root /home/git/;
    }

    # requests that need to go to git-http-backend
    location ~ ^.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$ {
        root /home/git/;

        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $uri;
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT  $document_root;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Remove all conf beyond if you don't want Gitweb
    try_files $uri @gitweb;
    location @gitweb {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $uri;
        fastcgi_param GITWEB_CONFIG     /etc/gitweb.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

You have to install Git, Gitweb and FastCgiWrap :

```
sudo apt-get install git gitweb fcgiwrap
```

For TLS, I use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) free certificates.

```
sudo letsencrypt certonly -d git.example.com --rsa-key-size 4096
```

To access Gitweb, just browse to git.example.com. You will also need to configure it to set the repositories' root :

```
sudo vim /etc/gitweb.conf
```

In order to get HTTP Basic Auth, you have to use the `htpasswd` command to add users to `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd`:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd username
```

Remove the `-c` switch the next time you run the command, because it only creates the file (Nginx doesn't have a .htpasswd file by default in its configuration directory).

If you want something more complex, powerful, GitHub-like, check [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/).

Comment: I now this is a pretty old post, but I can't seem to get push working - it always results in a `504`. I made only minor adjustments to your config. Have you ever got this working?

Comment: Yes, it was working (and it's still working in fact, but didn't touched it since that answer).

Comment: Would you mind looking up the fcgiwrap and git versions you have installed? I'd be willing to sponsor you a beer should you ever come to Germany :)

Comment: Aha, how could I refuse that :) --
git 2.11.0 / fcgiwrap 1.1.0

Comment: I also got HTTP 504 errors (gateway timeout) with push at first; for me, this was caused by a permission problem: fcgiwrap ran as user `www-data`, but the git repository directories were owned by another user.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details, we need 3 components: `nginx`, `git-http-backend` and `fcgiwrap`.

- `git-http-backend` is a standalone excutable binary can be built from https://github.com/git/git . It's the official solution for handling git http/https access, I don't know if it is the best one that exists.
- Nginx do not have a built-in general FastCGI server(or I failed to find how to use nginx's `fastcgi_bind` correctly).
  So another fastcgi server should be used, like `fcgiwarp`( a good manual https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/ )
- Use `fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/cgi.sock;` in nginx config (reference to other answers)

`fastcgi` is not a must, and `git-http-backend` is not write only for fastcgi, and fastcgi is not simplest nor performance one.
for examples, I wrote a servlet to interact between nginx and git-http-backend, using nginx's `proxy_pass`, it also works!

Comment: Mind sharing your setup with proxy_pass?