# Fail to push changes to git repository via http proxied by Nginx

Tags: git, nginx, webdav

I am new to setting up an Git repository via http with Nginx (not Apache)
I found [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414227/how-to-serve-git-through-http-via-nginx-with-user-password), it seemed a very simple solution.

I was able to create a repository and use `git clone` commands, however when i try to push changes to remote repository, I got following message from client

```
#git push origin master
XML error: not well-formed (invalid token)
error: no DAV locking support on http://192.168.80.128/git/it-knowledge.git/
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Could anyone help me to figure out what mistakes I made ?
About DAV locking support, I searched and see some threads about DAV locking file with Apache, is there any equivalent configuration on NginX in order to push changes successfully ?

Below are my nginx configuration file for the git path, my nginx was already installed with `--with-http_dav_module` option

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  192.168.80.128;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    location ~ /git(/.*) {
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        create_full_put_path  on;
        dav_access  user:rw group:rw all:rw;
        autoindex  on;
        client_max_body_size  10G;
        fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /srv/git;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That guide refers to a [2010 article](https://www.toofishes.net/blog/git-smart-http-transport-nginx/).
A similar configuration is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/massar/9399764)

```
location ~ /git(/.*) {
    # Set chunks to unlimited, as the body's can be huge
    client_max_body_size            0;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
    include     fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
    fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /git;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $1;

    # Forward REMOTE_USER as we want to know when we are authenticated
    fastcgi_param   REMOTE_USER     $remote_user;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

Make sure your repos are in `~`, and that `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend` does exists (with a recent enough Git version)