# Configure Nginx proxy for bitbucket

Tags: git, nginx, bitbucket

I want to configure a Nginx as a proxy server as following:

```
(1) Client PC <-----> (2)Nginx <------> (3)Bitbucket
```

In that:

- `(3)` Bitbucket: I have created a repository, I can work with it via either ssh or https.

  - ssh: `git@bitbucket.org:myname/myproject.git`
  - https: `https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/myproject.git`
- `(1)` Client PC: from client I do not want to use directly domain bitbucket.org, instead of, I want to use address of Nginx server to conceal bitbucket.org domain. So I used to use Nginx.
- `(2)` Nginx: I already installed and configured, It works well for http web.

My problem is I do not know how to configure Nginx to work with git bitbucket.
Please help me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should configure NGiNX to be able to act as a git repo server to which you can push to.
Then a post-receive hook can push in turn to BitBucket.

That way, you are pushing to your NGiNX server which acts as a gatekeeper between you and BitBucket.

See "[How to serve GIT through HTTP via NGINX with user/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36362218/6309)" as a concrete example of NGiNX git repo server configuration.

Comment: What are the advantages of this approach? You can set up plenty of "gates" directly in Bitbucket Server if you need to - pre-receive or post-receive hooks, ref restrictions (aka branch permissions), and plugins like Yet Another Commit Checker let you do some powerful stuff. But your suggestion seems, at worst, dangerously overcomplicated.

Comment: @daveruinseverything the OP does not want to use directly domain bitbucket.org though

Comment: I misread this as Bitbucket Server (self-hosted), rather than Bitbucket Cloud. My bad @VonC, your advice makes sense if I actually read the question properly :D