# Trying to setup smart http git server with nginx: "The requested URL returned error: 502"

Tags: git, nginx, git-http-backend

I am trying to set up a server for a git repo by using [smart http](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) with nginx.
I followed the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553364.

Though when I execute `git clone http://mydomian.de/git/test`, it returns:

```
Cloning into 'xmlTest' ...
fatal: unable to access 'http://mydomain.de/git/test/': The requested URL returned error: 502
```

and the nginx error log prints twice:

```
2016/11/16 07:29:11 [error] 19219#0: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: myip, server: mydomain.de, request: "GET /git/test/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "mydomain.de"
```

I placed a bare git repo with the name test in /srv/git/.

I installed git-core.

I think fcgiwrap is running, becuase `sudo service fcgiwrap status` returns:

```
[ ok ] Checking status of FastCGI wrapper: fcgiwrap running.
```

This is the relevant part of the config I'm using for nginx:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/mydomain/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from mydomain.de
        server_name mydomain.de;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;  

        location ~ /git(/.*) {
                # fcgiwrap is set up to listen on this host:port
                fastcgi_pass  localhost:9001;
                include       fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
                # export all repositories under GIT_PROJECT_ROOT
                fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
                fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /srv/git;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $1;

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Thank in advance for any help ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to:

```
location ~ (/.*) {
  client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
  auth_basic "Git Login"; # Whatever text will do.
  auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/git/htpasswd";
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include the default fastcgi configs
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend; # Tells 
  fastcgi to pass the request to the git http backend executable
  fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
  fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git/html; # /var/www/git is the location of all of your git repositories.
  fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1; # Takes the capture group from our location directive and gives git that.
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; # Pass the request to fastcgi
}
```

important! the fastcgi_pass is must be last.

Answer (score -1):

per [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418525/nginx-not-starting-git-http-server/68737603#68737603) , you may need to check if nginx can write into directory of git repos.