# How to set username and password for a git repository?

Tags: git

I want build a blog website which build on git to save all user's blogs.Every user has a git repository in my git host.
Currently, I'm use nginx and git-http-backend to communicate git repo files.

So, how to set username and password for every user's git repository which make it as private?

In other word, is there a way to config which user can do what kind of  operation(pull/push/...) on a git?  (sorry for my English)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but [we are not customer support for GitHub](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). If you want to setup accounts/security/etc, you'll need to ask about it on their forums.

Comment: Some helpful GitHub articles... [Inviting collaborators to a personal repository](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) and [Permission levels for a user account repository](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/)

Comment: Hi, @JDB, I have remove the part of Company specify question. forbid is meaningful.

Comment: Git does not have any built-in security. If you need to manage accounts, protect branches or restrict access, you'll need to use a git server with those features, like GitHub. If you need help setting up or managing those features, then you need to reference their online documentation or contact their customer support.

Comment: @JDB I want build a website like Github on my host but just for write blog

Comment: In that case... if you are asking how to build a site from scratch, then your question is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). If you are asking for a tool or service recommendation, then your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve GIT through HTTP via NGINX with user/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414227/how-to-serve-git-through-http-via-nginx-with-user-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) or [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) to serve your git repositories.

Both of these projects are git servers (e.g : they manage push / pull / clone actions), with user access built on top.

gitlab may be too big for what you describe in this question, but it comes with a nice GUI.

Comment: gitolite has a nice way to hold premission on git host! Gitlab too heavy in my situation.