# gitk: "Cannot find a git repository here" when running in WSL 2

Tags: git, wsl-2, gitk

I am trying to run gitk.exe (the program installed with Git for Windows) from WSL 2. If I do this in a repository sitting on my WSL virtual drive, such as ~/path/to/repository, I get the error, "Cannot find a git repository here." However if I'm in a repository outside of the virtual drive, i.e., /mnt/c/path/to/repository, gitk.exe works just fine even though I'm still running it from WSL. How can I get gitk.exe to work on repositories in my WSL filesystem?

Comment: Maybe there is no repository in `~/path/to/repository`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11969841/3882118) answer, gitk runs git under the hood to determine if it's being run in a git repository. So, it's reasonable to think that gitk.exe would run git.exe-that is, the binary installed on Windows, **not** the binary installed from my package manager in the WSL virtual drive.

Running `git.exe status` from my ~/path/to/repository/ resulted in:

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/myusername/path/to/repository' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///wsl$/Ubuntu/home/myusername/path/to/repository'
```

To fix this I first tried running in WSL

```
git.exe config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///wsl%/Ubuntu/home/myusername/path/to/repository'
```

But for some reason, that did not resolve the error. The next thing I tried was running the same command from a Git Bash window on Windows. After that, running `git.exe status` from WSL resulted in

```
On branch master

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And with that, `gitk.exe` also worked.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71941707/3882118) answer has some more information about the unsafe repository error.