# Facing issues while upgrading git to latest version on CentOS 6.4

Tags: git

I have Centos VM with git 1.7.1.  I would like to upgrade to the latest version of git.  However when I try to upgrade using yum, it says nothing to do and does not upgrade the version.  Below is the output from yum command :

```
# yum install git

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * updates: centos.aol.in
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                          | 3.4 MB     01:18
extras                                                   | 3.5 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                        |  19 kB     00:00
jenkins                                                  |  951 B     00:00
jenkins/primary                                          |  22 kB     00:01
jenkins
jenkins                                                  |  951 B     00:00
jenkins/primary                                          |  22 kB     00:01
jenkins                                                                 204/204
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                       | 4.1 MB     02:08
Setting up Install Process
Package git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Please help me for upgrading to latest version of git on Centos 6.4...

Comment: 1.7.1 is the latest version of git for CentOS 6.4. If you need a newer version, then you have either to find a newer rpm somewhere, or compile yourself.

Comment: Ask on superuser.com; stackoverflow.com is for programming-related questions, not general sysadmin questions like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can git be installed on CENTOS 5.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779274/how-can-git-be-installed-on-centos-5-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest version of git on CentOS 6.x/7.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820715/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos-6-x-7-x)

Answer (score 2):

Install Latest git version through compiling source...

http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/