# Installing GITK in Amazon EC2 Linux AMI 2014.03.1

Tags: git

I installed GIT (distributed revision control and source code management) system using yum install GIT.  Now to install GITK (GUI for GIT) I would think it would be in the same repository as GIT, ergo a yum install GITK should work, but it returns 'No package gitk available'.  (on a different CENTos installation the yum install gitk worked, so it must not be in the local repository).  Where would I find a repository containing GITK [that is in url format eg. [https://www.example.com/repository.repo]](https://www.example.com/repository.repo%5d)?  (not finding any with google).

Comment: would http://stackoverflow.com/a/3779476/6309 help?

Comment: thx, i had a look at it.  Still not able to find GITK in a repository and get it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I got past it by installing the 'git-gui' package, which will also install gitk:

```
yum install -y git-gui
```