# Install node.js using alternate install of PYTHON

Tags: python, linux, node.js, python-2.7, installation

My server is running CentOS 5.8 and uses PYTHON 2.4

I installed an alternate version of PYTHON 2.7 to use to install node.js

I have followed several different tutorials to get to this point and need a little help to finish

i am in the node directory and used this command for configure

```
/usr/bin/env python2.7 ./configure
```

when I ran the `make` command there was an error.

```
     File "../../tools/js2c.py", line 387
    except Error as e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make[1]: *** [/root/node/out/Release/obj/gen/libraries.cc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/node/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

I believe that's because it's using the 2.4 version of python. How can I force the `make` and `make install` command use my alternate install of python 2.7?

I'm a complete beginner to linux commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by doing the following. Full process

1. `yum update -y`
2. `yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"`
3. installed git ... followed this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327476/888640)
4. Installed alternate version of PYTHON
5. `wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz`
6. `tar -xvzf Python-2.7.2.tgz`
7. `cd Python-2.7.2`
8. `./configure`
9. `make altinstall`
10. `cd`
11. use the correct python version
12. `mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.old`
13. `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`
14. install node
15. `cd node`
16. `./configure`
17. `make`
18. `make install`
19. change back to normal version of python
20. `mv /usr/bin/python.old /usr/bin/python`