# Linux not finding Git package for install

Tags: linux, git, fedora

I followed the steps mentioned on Git website to install Git. but I am seeing the message that Git package is not available.

Link: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

```
yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
Setting up Install Process
Package curl-devel-7.15.5-9.el5.i386 already installed and latest version
Package expat-devel-1.95.8-8.3.el5_4.2.i386 already installed and latest version
Package gettext-devel-0.14.6-4.el5.i386 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-devel-0.9.8e-12.el5_4.6.i386 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-3.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do


 yum install git
Setting up Install Process
No package git available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can git be installed on CENTOS 5.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779274/how-can-git-be-installed-on-centos-5-5)

Comment: What OS? CentOS? Fedora? Some strange Ubuntu based distro that uses RPM?

Comment: And what OS version? Some older versions don't have git in the repo so you have to compile git yourself. Some newer versions of some OSes have very old versions of git in the repo so you should compile git yourself as well.

Comment: Looks like you are on Fedora 12 or RHEL5.x, in addition to the above also try adding the correct repo and refreshing it before doing an `yum install`