# RPM package spec localization

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, rpm-spec

I need to package proprietary program for Russian local market.
To build RPM package, i used this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165200/1794089

So, i need to translate RPM package description to Russian, i.e. localize them.
I'm googled that method:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2004-January/msg00062.html

But it not work: in Fedora 21 x64 software installation center still show package summary/description in English - while system locale is ru_RU.UTF-8.

What am i doing wrong?

SPEC file fragment:

```
...
Summary: Test
Summary(ru): Тест
...
License: Proprietary
...

%description
 Test application

%description -l ru
 Тестовое приложение
```

Answer (score 1):

The link (https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2004-January/msg00062.html)
you posted mentions specspo: specspo is a look aside cache for the group/description/summary tags that is in gettext PO format to simplify
translating large scale distro-wide translations of package metadata.

Short answer: If specspo is installed, then group/summary/description
tags in the package are not used.

Comment: Okay, but is there any documentaion about `specspo`?
I'm unable to google smth like tutorial/example of this :(

Comment: Documentation of what? The RPM piece of the puzzle is a 2 level lookup

Comment: Documentation of what? The RPM piece of the puzzle is a 2 level look aside lookup, first using package metadata to get the msgid (from the unused "en_US" locale, then using the retrieved msgid to find the localized msgstr ro return from headerGet. How to manage the specspo translation process is a distro, not an rpm, functionality.

Comment: The code that does the look aside retrieval for group/summary/description can be found by grep'ing for "en_US" in rpm sources. The distro translation process is far more complex.

Comment: Hint: Uninstall the specspo package and rpm will use the tags in the header, not the look aside cache retrieved values.

Comment: Documentaion about `specspo` usage from scratch. Also, i'm never used `gettext` at all, so all this stuff is hard to understand for me :/ Okay, i will read `rpm` sources to understand how it find localized description string...

Comment: Yes the translation process is hard to understand, though conceptually simple. Basically PO files are (key, val) pairs called (msgid,msgstr). get text is passed a msgid and returns the msgstr (from the appropriate locale file).

Comment: All that rpm is doing is a 2 level lookup: so msgid= gettext(pkgname) in the en_US locale, and then msgstr = get text(msgid) in the appropriate locale, for each of group/summary/description tags.

Comment: For a proprietary packaging outside of the Fedora distro, erasing the specspo package and using tags from the package is likely going to be the only (and imperfect) choice permitted.